# full height sidebar contains extra space at end of page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, sidebar, bootstrap-5.1

I'm having an issue with trying to create a bootstrap 5.1 full sidebar layout and i keep getting extra space at the bottom of the page. Can anyone help me figure out how to correct this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HD</title>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=pAGv4ietcJNk_EwsQZ5BN9-K4MuNYS2a9wl4Jw-q9D0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cook.HelpDesk.WebUI.styles.css?v=-Gg8kUnMhQ-2coBbOSS0jxtLbjK3ZnpdxOGTNKMhq7k" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
       body {
            font-family: Poppins,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        }

        div svg * {
            fill: url(#rg);
        }

        .nav-menu {
            color: #ededee;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: #1e1e2d;
            width: 265px;
            color: #626274;
        }


        .sidebar-header {
            background-color: #1a1a27;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        #menu {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .nav-menu li {
            padding-left: 40px;
            background-color: #1e1e2d;
            height: 40px;
        }

            .nav-menu li.active {
                background-color: #1b1b28;
            }

        .nav-menu a {
            color: #898a9c;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        .nav-menu li.active a {
            color: #ededee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="container-fluid">
        <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="row flex-nowrap">
            <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="col-auto col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-0 m-0 sidebar">
                <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-0 pt-0 text-white min-vh-100">

                    <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="flex-column p-3 sidebar-header">
                        HelpDesk
                    </div>
                    <ul b-w8sqswn6sv class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 nav-menu " id="menu">
                        <li b-w8sqswn6sv class="nav-item">
                            <a b-w8sqswn6sv href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0 ">
                                <span b-w8sqswn6sv class="fa fa-tasks" style="width:20px;"></span><span b-w8sqswn6sv class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline ">Tickets</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li b-w8sqswn6sv class="nav-item active">
                            <a b-w8sqswn6sv href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0 ">
                                <span b-w8sqswn6sv class="fa-solid fa-receipt" style="width:20px;"></span><span b-w8sqswn6sv class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline ">New Ticket</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li b-w8sqswn6sv>
                            <a b-w8sqswn6sv href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                <span b-w8sqswn6sv class="fa fa-users-cog " style="width:20px;"></span><span b-w8sqswn6sv class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">User Admin</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li b-w8sqswn6sv>
                            <a b-w8sqswn6sv href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                <span b-w8sqswn6sv class="fa fa-th-large" style="width:20px;"></span><span b-w8sqswn6sv class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="col p-0 m-0" style="background-color:#f2f5f7;">


                <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="mb-3 p-3" style="background-color:white">
                    <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="dropdown pb-4 float-end" style="height:25px;">
                        <a b-w8sqswn6sv href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i b-w8sqswn6sv class="fa fa-circle-user fs-3 " style="color: #f4f7fa;"></i>

                            <span b-w8sqswn6sv class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">user</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul b-w8sqswn6sv class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                            <li b-w8sqswn6sv><a b-w8sqswn6sv class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li b-w8sqswn6sv>
                                <hr b-w8sqswn6sv class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li b-w8sqswn6sv><a b-w8sqswn6sv class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="clearfix"></div>
                    <hr b-w8sqswn6sv />
                    
    <text>New Ticket</text>


                </div>
                <div b-w8sqswn6sv class="p-5" style="background-color:white;margin-right:100px; margin-left:100px;margin-top:50px;">

                    
<div class="col panel-body">
<form action="/" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><span>Please correct the indicated errors.</span>
<ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div><input id="TicketId" name="TicketId" type="hidden" value="" /><input id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId" type="hidden" value="" />            <div class="row">
               

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span><label>*Category:</label></span>

                    <div class="parentDiv">
                        <div class="item1">
                            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="1st Category cannot be null or empty." id="MainCategoryId" name="MainCategoryId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Login Access</option>
<option value="2">Hardware</option>
<option value="3">Equipment Request</option>
<option value="4">Software</option>
</select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span><label>Department:</label></span>
                    <p><select class="form-control" id="DepartmentId" name="DepartmentId"><option value="1">ADMINISTRATION</option>
</select></p>

                </div>

            </div>
         
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span><label>Contact Number:</label></span>
                    <p><input class="form-control" id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" type="text" value="" /></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span><label>Contact Location:</label></span>
                    <p><input class="form-control" id="ContactLocation" name="ContactLocation" type="text" value="" /></p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div id="divECControls">

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span><label>Upload File:</label></span>
                    <p>
                        <label class="btn-file">
                            <span class="fa fa-paperclip"></span> Browse <input name="files" id="uploadFile" type="file" style="display: none;" multiple ="">
                        </label>
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline;" id="spnFile"></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="w-100">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;width:15%;">
                                <strong><a href="/"> <i class="fa fa-undo fa-lg"></i> Clear</a></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;">
                                <button id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8MIs1TeupyFApFJevlKJ0yEeRzfbZKHXM_ZM9ySpSMSZc3v8psitxmZgiWcJGk_zdjH1ikcl02TeIXhfCVsHofqIDiVIpkDtuKSYLsLRgsGSCbANfRpdzBdeaHZDX-WBx4HLvcHezxRaijEtClzFKFsrCQv8m-WApRzt00VqLtZUVoZxPbBUPLSa2r_S3XHCog" /></form></div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>





   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <svg b-w8sqswn6sv width="0" height="0">
        <radialGradient b-w8sqswn6sv id="rg" r="150%" cx="30%" cy="107%">
            <stop b-w8sqswn6sv stop-color="#134266 " offset="0" />
            <stop b-w8sqswn6sv stop-color="#134266" offset="0.05" />
            <stop b-w8sqswn6sv stop-color="#009ef7" offset="0.45" />
            <stop b-w8sqswn6sv stop-color="#009ef7" offset="0.6" />
            <stop b-w8sqswn6sv stop-color="#009ef7" offset="0.9" />
        </radialGradient>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the html elements,this div `.container-fluid` doesn't fill the body
[image]
[image]

I tried with css codes:

```
.container-fluid {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            bottom:0px;
        }
```

there're no extra space at the bottom now:
[image]